# Open soft keyboard emoticons

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When I clicked on button I would like to open soft keyboard with type emoticons (default system emoticons). Any idea?

[image]

Comment: search for android:inputType="textShortMessage"

Comment: it doesn't work, I searched the whole stackoverflow and haven't found working solution

Comment: it's better to share source code to find where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not possible to do that without external libraries. Check out this library that provides  a Whatsapp style emoji keyboard: https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon. I don't think there is a solution for the official Google emoji set.